# How to CI with Travis, Codedeploy and dockerized Database

Tags: git, mongodb, docker-compose, travis-ci, aws-code-deploy

I'm currently developing a **node.js** project based on `docker-compose`, which handles the app itself and a **mongo** database. In the database is an initial user stored.

I've got an idea how it should work initially:

1. publish repo incl. the initial db data on github
2. triggering **travis** ci to test/lint
3. triggering **codedeploy** to deploy to ec2 instance
4. run build command and run `docker-compose up`

Now the app should be online. While the production mode the database gets some more data. When pushing again to master, it should deploy again but must not override the live data with the initial data on github. Currently the whole process works but still overrides the data. I ran the following command on both the local and the remote machine, but without any success:

`cd ./data && git ls-files | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs git update-index --assume-unchanged`

I thought that **codedeploy** just pulls the current master branch but ignores the `./data` directory because of the command above and the `.gitignore` file. But it does not seem so.

So is there anything that's missed so far? Hope you've got some hints and ideas how to solve this issue.

Thanks a lot!!
p.s. following some information and file excerpts.

---

**System Details**

- Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
- node: v6.9.1
- npm: 3.10.8
- docker: 1.12.3
- docker-compose: 1.8.1
- git: 1.91

---

**File structure**

```
config/                           # Some config files
data/                             # The database its directory
src/                              # The source files
.gitignore
.travis.yml
appspec.yml
docker-compose.yml
```

---

Here are some file excerpts:

**.gitignore**

```
data/*
```

**.travis.yml**

```
language: node_js
sudo: required
dist: trusty
node_js:
- 6
before_script:
- npm install
script:
- npm run lint
branches:
  only:
  - master
deploy:
  provider: codedeploy
  wait-until-deployed: true
  access_key_id: 'mykeyid'
  secret_access_key: 'myaccesskey'
  application: appname
  deployment_group: grpname
  region: eu-central-1
```

**appspec.yml**

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ubuntu/app
permissions:
  - object: /
    pattern: "**"
    owner: ubuntu
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  server:
    image: node:6
    command: 'npm run go'
    working_dir: '/app'
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - '1337:1337'
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=prod
    links:
      - mongo:mongodb
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - ./data/:/data/db
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I see that `data` is in your `.gitignore`, but were some files committed to that folder first? Note that `git update-index --assume-unchanged` is a local command, and won't affect any remote repos, so that's probably not what you want.

Comment: Yep, the initial data are on github. The `data` entry in `.gitignore` was added after the commit/push. Yeah, I know it's a local command. But I ran the command on the remote machine and hoped that the data directory doesn't get overwritten because git says that nothing has changed.

Comment: So what is the goal? I assume you don't want to just remove the file from the repo now that the data has been imported? Do you just want a way to import the data only if no data exists?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I just want a way to import the data only if no data exists. So that there is an initial state. But as soon as the live/remote system has additional data, it should not be overwritten anymore.

Comment: How is the data imported currently?

Comment: To the remote system? With the github-travis-codedeploy pipeline..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126925/discussion-between-fheck-and-scott-weldon).